# Setting up subdomains, confused on "Settings.php" / "web.config" setup

Tags: 7, configuration

First, I'm using shared hosting.  I've set up the DNS so I have one.example.com, two.example.com, etc.  Each subdomain works properly, but they use the default page.tpl.php/look exactly the same as my front page.  I'm assuming the next step is to configure the settings.php, web.config, and to create preprocessed theme hooks.  Is there a good D7 tutorial on how to do all of this via "subdomains"?

Also, I'm planning on using the "Domain" module.  I've got it properly configured.  But, don't really see a point in using it until the above mentioned is setup properly.

Answer (score 2):

Instructions for multisite installations are in `sites/default/settings.php`. To quote from that file:

> For example, for a fictitious site installed at http://www.drupal.org/mysite/test/, the 'settings.php' is searched in the following directories:
>
> 1. sites/www.drupal.org.mysite.test
> 2. sites/drupal.org.mysite.test
> 3. sites/org.mysite.test
> 4. sites/www.drupal.org.mysite
> 5. sites/drupal.org.mysite
> 6. sites/org.mysite
> 7. sites/www.drupal.org
> 8. sites/drupal.org
> 9. sites/org
> 10. sites/default
>
> If you are installing on a non-standard port number, prefix the hostname with that number. For example, http://www.drupal.org:8080/mysite/test/ could be loaded from sites/8080.www.drupal.org.mysite.test/.

The lookup can be changed as described in `sites/example.sites.php`:

> This file allows you to define a set of aliases that map hostnames and pathnames to configuration directories. These aliases are loaded prior to scanning for directories, and they are exempt from the normal discovery rules. The aliases are defined in an associative array named $sites, which should look similar to the following:
>
> ```
> $sites = array(
>   'devexample.com' => 'example.com',
>   'localhost.example' => 'example.com',
> );
> ```
>
> The above array will cause Drupal to look for a directory named "example.com" in the sites directory whenever a request comes from "example.com", "devexample.com", or "localhost/example".

BTW: multisite installations are usually done to facilitate using different databases.